# Transporting function calls between threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, assembly, stack, cpu-registers

I'm facing a very challenging task. Which is somewhat easy to describe but its hard to implement, and I'm really don't know how to do it. Maybe someone knows a easier way:

I want to save the parameters (stack and registers) of a function call into the heap, and after that restore these parameters in a another thread.

Suppose the following function:

```
int worker(int p1, int p2, ...) // variadic
{
  return enq(); // will pack the parameters and return a Job structure

  ... // some heavy work that must be executed by another thread
}
```

My starting point are two structures, the first holds the current stack frame

```
struct StackFrame
{
  struct StackFrame *next;
  void *returnAddr;
};
```

And the second holds the saved parameters and the worker's returning point

```
struct Job
{
  void *registers[];
  size_t regCount; 

  void *stackFrame;
  size_t frameSize;  

  void *workerAddr;  
};
```

Now, the function `enq()` it will pack the worker parameters, and enqueue the Job using a thread pool (already working). I foresaw something like this:

```
Job* enq()
{ 
  // get the caller stackFrame 
  register struct StackFrame *fp __builtin_frame_address(1);

  // save the stack parameters of the caller to the heap,
  Job *job = new Job;
  job->frameSize = frame->next - frame;
  job->frameContent = malloc (job->frameSize);
  memcpy (job->stackContent, frame, job->frameSize );

  job->workerAddr = frame.workerAddr // to where the worker Thread will jump 

  // !! I'm stuck here !! 

  // copy all the registers to memory (ideally only the used as parameters)
  job.registers = ... // in i32 there was an instruction called PUSHA, but not on i64

  return job // real, threadPool.push(job)
}
```

Now, on the worker side, the `deq()` function will do the reverse of `enq()`, something like this:

```
void deq(Job *job) 
{ 
  // real, Job *job = threadPool.pop()

  // restore the registers parameters
  POPA(job->registers, job->regCount) // just like (i32 POPA)

  // restore the stack frame. 
  push(job->frameContent, job->frameSize) 

  // execute the worker 
  call(job->workerAddr);

  // mark the Job as done
}
```

In the client side, I want call this function just as:

```
  Job* promise = worker(1, 2, "a variadic param");
  wait(promise); // or wait(promise, callback)
```

The `enq()` function must pack the parameters of caller into the Job structure from inside the worker function.

The `wait()` function is not a real problem, and is here to exemplify how the whole thing must work.

This all I have.

Do you know how can a solve any of these missing steps, and help me get a little closer of my intent? Or even better, a simpler and higher level way to do this?

I'm using GCC 9.2.1 on Ubuntu 19 64 bits.

Comment: Well it's certainly non-standard, but you seem to be okay with that. Is there a reason you can't just use something like std::function though?

Comment: Nice idea. Thanks, (I really don't master std, and was missing std::function) I will investigate how I can use it. Meanwhile, do you have some idea/example of use how to use it?

Comment: `std::function<int(int)> f = [](int arg) {return arg*2;};` (the `[](){}` thing is called a lambda) `int j = f(2); // j is 4`. Lambdas can store values as part of the lambda (called captures) - look it up

Comment: You want to implement the common OS task of context switching? Is this correct?

Comment: I created a [lock-free queue](https://github.com/bittnkr/uniq) and I'm implementing a thread pool. Currently I'm passing parameters as structures, but I want to hide the implementation details of the user and use it simply calling a function.

Comment: Unrelated, but it is sad that we still don't have a standard thread pool to call in C++.

Comment: You're using `asm("ebp")` which is a 32-bit register.  Are you writing 32-bit code with its inefficient but simpler stack-args calling convention? (It's still unsafe because asm-register local vars are only guaranteed to do anything as inputs to asm statements.  And more importantly because `-fomit-frame-pointer` is on by default so there's no guarantee that EBP or RBP are even being used as a frame pointer.  Perhaps you want `__builtin_frame_address(0)` or `(1)`?  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Return-Address.html

Comment: @PeterCordes: I don't knew about `__builtin_frame_address()`. All that code is just a seed of thought which I wrote right on the SE question box. I will change that on my local code. Thanks for pointing that.

Comment: (edit, you already fixed this): I think actually you just want `__builtin_frame_address(1)`.  Of course your whole approach seems to assume only stack args so that's not viable, unless your only args are large structs (larger than 16 bytes for x86-64 System V).  Perhaps you could declare your function as taking a large struct by value and simply copy it; whatever struct you actually pass would be at most that size.  So maybe a union.

Comment: The worker function may accept any kind of parameters, hence he variadic mention. But `enq()` & `deq()` must be parameter-less (despite I putting a `job` parameter in the example  `deq()`) they will make role of a man-in the-midle for and  external Queue() object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a very simple and effective solution implementing your enq and deq (with minor changes for the sake of brevity).

I left an earlier solution with inline assembly because you mentioned registers and the stack, but this solution doesn't require any assembly and will work for any function with any number and type of parameters.

For quick review, the "stack and registers" are stored in ThreadFunction instances. You simply use ThreadFunction::Call to invoke the stored function with its stored parameters. The main function is very simple and just uses enq and deq with some threads, but you can use GetThreadInvokable to pack a function and its arguments into a ThreadFunction object, which you can then enqueue whenever you need to.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include <functional>
#include <mutex>
using namespace std;

struct ThreadFunction {
    virtual void Call() = 0;
};

template <typename F, typename ... Args>
struct ThreadFunctionPacked : public ThreadFunction {
    std::function<void(void)> m_lambda;

    ThreadFunctionPacked(F pFunc, Args ... args) {
        m_lambda = [pFunc, args...]() {
            pFunc(args...);
        };
    }

    virtual void Call() {
        m_lambda();
    }
};

template <typename F, typename ... Args>
ThreadFunction* GetThreadInvokable(F pFunc, Args... args) {
    ThreadFunction* ret = (ThreadFunction*) new ThreadFunctionPacked<F, Args...> (pFunc, args...);
    return ret;
}

struct Job {
    ThreadFunction* m_funcAndArgs = NULL;
    Job(ThreadFunction* p) {
        m_funcAndArgs = p;
    }

    void Run() {
        m_funcAndArgs->Call();
    }
};

std::mutex mutexJobs;
std::vector<Job*> jobs;
std::mutex mutexConsole;

template <typename F, typename ... Args>
void enq(F pFunc, Args... args) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutexJobs);
    jobs.push_back(new Job(GetThreadInvokable(pFunc, args...)));
}

void deq() {
    Job* job = NULL;
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutexJobs);
        if (jobs.empty()) {
            return;
        }

        job = jobs[0];
        jobs.erase(jobs.begin());
    }

    if (job != NULL) {
        job->Run();
    }
}

void testAdd(int a, int b) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutexConsole);
    cout << a + b << endl;
}

void testMinus(int a, int b) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutexConsole);
    cout << a - b << endl;
}

void testVoid() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutexConsole);
    cout << "Void function" << endl;
}

void testPrint(std::string str) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutexConsole);
    cout << str << endl;
}

void thread1Func() {
    deq();
    deq();
    deq();
}

void thread2Func() {
    deq();
    deq();
    deq();
}

int main() {
    enq(testAdd, 5, 3);
    enq(testAdd, 10, 50);
    enq(testMinus, 7, 20);
    enq(testVoid);
    enq(testPrint, "Hello");

    std::thread t1(thread1Func);
    std::thread t2(thread2Func);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see I used a couple of mutexes for proof-of-concept threading, but you should make this more robust with a threadpool in your solution as you have planned, and also notice that I didn't implement any destructors or do any deleting of dynamic memory which you should do of course (wrapping the pointers in std::unique_ptr should suffice).

I'll leave my earlier solution up in case anyone wants to dabble in register and stack management, but I think you'll be happiest with this solution.

Comment: testFlip should probably do the work *before* taking `lock(mutexConsole)`, and you can/should just use `\n` instead of `std::endl` - cout is line buffered on a TTY or full-buffered otherwise and that's generally fine without extra manual flushing.  Also, this only compiles on gcc/clang with `-std=gnu++17`, otherwise `std::reverse` isn't defined.  `#include <algorithm>` to fix that - https://godbolt.org/z/hLEyCH (It runs ok on my Arch Linux machine; running on Godbolt doesn't work because I guess Godbolt doesn't allow multiple threads.)

Comment: Of course popping the front of a `std::vector` is not efficient; `.back()` and `.pop_back()` would be a simple way to use a vector as a LIFO stack for example purposes, instead of a circular buffer FIFO.  I was curious how this compiled into asm; where the compiler put the args and how it accessed them.  A simplified `deq` without locking or a memmove loop to erase the first element is https://godbolt.org/z/XDauB2

Comment: Ah I see, templates and virtual functions result in custom code for every different kind of arg you use, and vtable dispatch in the worker side runs corresponding code that loads just the correct args from memory into the right arg-passing registers.  Not some kind of "generic" parameter pack object at the asm level.  That's fine; for anything worth dispatching to a worker thread, extra vtable indirection is minor to negligible, and using just pure C++ to get the compiler to jump through hoops for you is a big advantage.

Comment: @PeterCordes  is correct about the performance considerations. I threw this up here quickly to get the asker an answer. A queue would probably be a more appropriate data structure, and nevertheless the asker said that they have their own design prepared. The important concept being demonstrated here is storage of variadic template constructor arguments into a lambda via captures for later invokation. Also important is the polymorphism used by subclassing the non-templated ThreadFunction class and invoking the stored lambda in overriden `Call`

Comment: Indeed, the performance of the way you're using `std::vector` is irrelevant because nobody should use it.  I just didn't want the noise in the asm output I was looking at to find out how the actual dispatch mechanism worked in asm, before I noticed that it was just vtables, not one generic dispatch code path for different arg types like your hand-written asm does.  As far as efficiency, this dispatch is fine.  Fully hand-written asm could maybe have one fewer level of indirection but at a huge cost in portability / maintainability.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for verifying the efficiency of my dispatching method. Yes, this is probably the best way to do it. The compiler is able to codify the function call in effectively the same way as a manually typed invokation and can thus conform to the x64 calling convention (with efficient register-passing of parameters) as the asker wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar problem a while back. In my case the functions I needed to call were all void. So what I did was to use `std::bind` with [parameter pack templates](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) and store the result in a `std::vector<std::function<void()>>`. To return a specific type you could also return a `std::future<T>` as you enqueue the "Jobs". To return a random type you might be able to return a `std::future<std::any>` and leave it to the caller to cast it to the correct type. You can take a look at my implementation [here](https://github.com/daravi/schedule).

Comment: Nice. In my case, the functions will allways return the same type too. Not void but a Job ID, which is like a handle to a future/promise. But instead of `s.registerCall(std::chrono::system_clock::now() + 5000ms, &foo, 42);`, I want to just call `int promise = foo(42); wait(promise)` and call an `enq()` inside `foo()`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick example solution that does what you want (note that it uses Visual Studio inline assembler syntax, so it might slightly differ from GCC's syntax. It works for functions with any number of parameters but you'd have to find a way of getting a return type from the invoked function if you wanted to (it would be trivial if they all return the same type of value, but the sky's the limit).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
vector<pair<size_t, void*>> PackParams(T param) {
    vector<pair<size_t, void*>> ret;
    T* paramMem = new T;
    memcpy(paramMem, &param, sizeof(T));
    ret.push_back(pair<size_t, void*>(sizeof(T), paramMem));

    return ret;
}

template <class T, typename... Targs>
vector<pair<size_t, void*>> PackParams(T param, Targs... otherParams) {
    vector<pair<size_t, void*>> ret;
    T* paramMem = new T;
    memcpy(paramMem, &param, sizeof(T));
    ret.push_back(pair<size_t, void*>(sizeof(T), paramMem));

    vector<pair<size_t, void*>> otherPack = PackParams(otherParams...);

    for (int i = 0; i < otherPack.size(); ++i) {
        ret.push_back(otherPack[i]);
    }

    return ret;
}

vector<pair<size_t, void*>> PackParams(void) {
    vector<pair<size_t, void*>> ret;
    return ret;
}

pair<size_t, void*> AlignParams(vector<pair<size_t, void*>> params) {
    int totalSize = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < params.size(); ++i) {
        totalSize += params[i].first;
    }

    char* paramBlock = new char[totalSize];

    totalSize = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < params.size(); ++i) {
        memcpy(&paramBlock[totalSize], params[i].second, params[i].first);
        totalSize += params[i].first;
    }

    return pair<size_t, void*>(totalSize, paramBlock);
}

int test1(int a, int b) {
    cout << a + b << endl;
    return a + b;
}

void Call(void* pFunc, void* params, int paramSize) {
    _asm {
        mov edx, paramSize
        mov ebx, params
        xor ecx,ecx
        loop1:
        push dword ptr [ebx + ecx]
        add ecx, 4
        cmp ecx,paramSize
        jl loop1
        call pFunc
        add esp, paramSize
        nop
    }

}

int main() {
    vector<pair<size_t, void*>> r = PackParams(5, 6);

    pair<size_t,void*> paramData = AlignParams(r);

    Call(test1, paramData.second, paramData.first);

    //system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Pass paramData and the function pointer to the threads and they can use the Call function.

Warnings:

You will have to implement a correct AlignParams function to ensure 4-byte, 8-byte, or whatever alignment is achieved depending on your system architecture's requirements.

This answer conforms to the x86 stdcall calling convention. Other calling conventions require different assembly, especially x64 which has some radical departures in certain scenarios.

Also, in the interest of quickly giving you a solution, I omitted some basic memory handling (didn't delete dynamically allocated memory, etc.). This is just a demonstrative solution to show you generally what you will have to do for a more robust solution.

Also, you can combine Call, PackParams, and AlignParams into a single variadic template function for simpler syntax of course.

Comment: Given that 32-bit code is basically obsolete (especially on Linux), and the x86-64 System V calling convention passes args in registers (up to 6 integer *and* up to 8 FP, unlike Windows x64 where you can put args in both integer and FP slots in generic wrappers), nothing this simplistic can work easily.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer and effort. Currently, I'm packing my parameters in a structure/object and then pushing that structures onto the queue. So, my calls always have a single parameter. (Take a look on my repos, to understand how I'm using the Queue). I really don't see advantage in packing the params how you did. I would like to hide the details from the caller of the lib, and using just  as `Job test = test1(10, 20)` and  after that `wait(test)`. The function enq() must take care of packing the parameters inside `test1()`.

Comment: @PeterCordes You don't need to write an x64 app to run on x64 operating systems. I ran my x86 sample app posted here on x64 Windows just fine.

Also, my solution provides a structure of saving runtime information that can be used for further improvements (e.g. tracking floating points to store in XMM registers).

This is a minimum information necessary solution, and it's probably good enough for what the asker wants. If not, then they can study the calling conventions and change what they need.

Comment: @bittnkr The packing of params isn't strictly necessary in this example, but for implementing modern calling conventions it can allow you to add the necessary information to put values in the proper registers.

Also you can use that exact syntax you just requested with the given solution. I'll edit it to demonstrate if you accept the solution. Basically, I'll combine the three different templated functions into a simple Job function that will return a handle to a thread that you can wait on.

Comment: I will study you solution, and try to adapt it for my needs, but I can't compile it, because I don't have a Windows machine. (And to be honest, I'm struggling to understand it.) I agree with @PeterCordes, when he said that we need to handle the register parameters of the x64 calling convention.This is a must have, and is my main problem of the question.

Comment: @bittnkr Okay then I will edit the answer to store integral variables or floating etc. in the proper registers and store extraneous parameters on the stack as the x64 calling convention specifies, but only if you accept my current answer because you didn't specify that you require x64 in your original question and made a vague reference to registers but without any details on what exactly what you wanted or how robust it should be.

Comment: I would love to accept you answer, but it don't meet my needs, that is hiding the params handling of the user. If you could evolve my example, and make the function enq() pack the parameters and save then into the Job structure, I will accept it.

Comment: Alex: I know you *can* run 32-bit code on a 64-bit OS but it's rarely done on Linux.  Using inefficient 32-bit code with its simple and inefficient calling convention just to make this one part of your program work doesn't seem like something @bittnkr is likely to want to do.  They did specify Ubuntu.  Demanding they accept this before you write a valid version that handles 16-byte stack alignment and 64-bit calling conventions is a bit of a stretch.

Comment: Beware that making function calls from GNU C inline asm is fraught with peril.  For example, you need to avoid clobbering the red zone (or compile this file with `-mno-red-zone`), and you'll need at least a `"memory"` clobber and all of the call-clobbered registers.  Also, stack stuff in inline asm could break stack unwinding through this function and thus exception handling.  (Because you won't have `.eh_frame` CFI metadata about where RSP points relative to the stack frame).  A pure C++ method would probably be better and safer.